# use php inside JavaScript

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have an ajax function that post to an PHP file.
Now since I'm using WordPress I can use the get_url function so I don't need to hard code the entire URL.

The WordPress function is an PHP so I'm trying to use PHP inside the ajax post. But it wont do the trick.
Any ideas ? and is it possible ?

This is what I have.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').click(function(){

$.post('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/send.php', $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {
$('#success').html(response);
//$('#success').hide('slow');
});
return false;

});

});
```

I have also tried the php echo inside quotes like this.

```
   $.post(' "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>" /send.php' ....
```

ether  way I get this path

```
http://mysite.com/%27%3C?php%20echo%20get_template_directory_uri();%20?%3E%27/send.php&email=&message=&name=&sent=1
```

Comment: Where are you using that code? In a JS file?

Comment: Unless this is placed in header.php (for example), it won't work. The WordPress template functions are only loaded in the template files. Apart from that, there's nothing wrong with the code (the first part above).

Comment: Yes, forgot too mention that.
was thinking of creating a variable but since in a js file it didnt to the trick

Comment: what you should do is rename the extension to php and include it as javascript it would work totaly fine like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript to PHP = nope you cant embed javascript to php, only php can embed html and javascripts.

the better way to do it is to create a .php file and insert the javascript there...

**Example: js.php**

```
<?php
    function doSubmit() {
        ?>
        <script>
            $('#submit').click(function(){
                $.post('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/send.php', $("#mycontactform").serialize(), function(response) {
                    $('#success').html(response);
                    //$('#success').hide('slow');
                    });
                return false;
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

call the js.php using "include(js.php);" and call the functions inside another php

**Inside your index.php**

```
<?php
include('js.php');
?>
<html>
    <head><script><?php doSubmit();?></script></head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alternatively, just put doSubmit() inside your functions.php file and you don't need to include the file. +1 anyway.

Comment: by the way yeah @Kieran is right, you could also do it...but my concept is to wide QStarter's imagination about php coding :)

Comment: Thanks. going to try this in a moment :) thanks alot @ChowKiko and the rest for all help

Comment: you may CHECK my post if my ANSWER is correct so that guest could identify the correct answer...thanks