# Pass form values into another php class through javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, image, forms

I have a MyAccount page for my website which is going to have a form to allow the users to upload an image.

```
<from action='javascript:uploadFile'>
     <input type='file' name='Upload'>
</form>
```

What I would like to do is have it call another .php file like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function uploadFile()
    {
         addPhoto.php giving files $id and Upload (from the form)
    }
```

How can I achieve this without the user actually leaving the MyAccount page?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241422/include-php-inside-javascript-js-file

Comment: Similarly to what I answered lately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852461/use-php-inside-javascript/15852578#15852578

Comment: Check http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `include` or `require` within a PHP file.

> The `include` statement includes and evaluates the specified file.

You would need AJAX/jQuery to call it through JavaScript.

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)